# Jquery when FadeIn() the Object it blinks,Ipad safari

Tags: jquery, css, ipad

I'm making a website intro, sliding photos and text etc.. 
Everything is working fine except on Ipad Safari Browser, every FadeIn() comes like the object blinks,it comes totally visible first then blinks, then fades In 
here is my demo http://benseno.com.tr/demo/viz/

and my CSS is :

```
.slide_p {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    display:none;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

and the one of the divs:

```
<div id="slide3" class="slide_p"
            style="width: 1100px; height: 763px; background-image: url('images/s_03.png'); margin-left: -550px; margin-top: -381px;">
        </div>
```

and JQuery is Quiet basic and straight forward something like this:

```
$("#slide3").fadeIn(2000);
```

and this started to drive me crazy, any suggestion for solving this?
btw don't try Ipad simulators, it does that only on my real Ipad.

Comment: Try setting `opacity: 0` to the element css rules.

Comment: Tried, it made nothing appears.

Comment: @Mahn Using `fadeTo(2000,1);` instead of `fadeIn(2000);` Did solve my Problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `fadeTo(2000,1);` instead of `fadeIn(2000);` Did solve my Problem.

Comment: You should accept this solution if it answered your question.

Comment: @JSuar I answered Myself :D, and I can't accept my own answer to my own question before 2 days of answering.

Comment: ah, forgot about that. Sorry :]