# jQuery image cycle flickering on iOS devices

Tags: jquery, ios

For the site I am currently building, I want to utilize cycling images for one section (IE a series of images crossfade in a single container.) As this is largely a learning process for me, I am writing most of the javascript and jQuery myself instead of using prebuilt plugins.

The cycle works perfectly (as far as I can tell) on all desktop browsers, but when tested on iOS devices, I get a flicker each time a section starts to cycle to a new image.

Basically, there are three functions that look like this:

```
function cycleTheatrical(){
   setTimeout(function(){
    (theatPos < (theatArray.length-1)) ? theatPos+=1 : theatPos = 0;
    $('#page-1-theatrical').append("<img src='" + theatArray[theatPos] + "' class='project-img' style='display:none'>");
    $('#page-1-theatrical img:last-child').fadeIn(1500, function(){
    $('#page-1-theatrical img:first').remove();
    });
    cycleHomeEnt();
}, 3000);
};
```

So what I am attempting to do is to append the new image with `display:none`, then fade it in over the old one. Once faded in, the callback function removed the old image.

When viewed in an iOS device, I see a brief flash of the new image, just for one fraction of a second, before it disappears and the cross fade happens normally. My first assumption was that the `display:none` was not getting set until after the image was set, so I build an alternate version that appended an image with no source set to `display:none`, then added a source in ( using .attr() ) before doing the fade, but the problem remained the same as before.

So does anyone know what causes this brief flicker on iOS devices? You can view the WIP site here, to see what I am talking about:

http://www.thecrpgroup.com/crpweb/promo-site/

Thanks for any help!

Comment: iOS 5.1.1, did not flicker for me.

Comment: I first checked it on an iPad running 6.1.3. I have since been testing using xcode's iOS device simulator, and the only version it seems to allow is 6.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why this is required, but I did find an answer. After working with it, I isolated the problem down to the fadeIn() call. This allowed me to narrow my searching, and I found this:

[Jquery when FadeIn() the Object it blinks,Ipad safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15271930/jquery-when-fadein-the-object-it-blinks-ipad-safari)

It turns out replacing fadeIn() with fadeTo() solved the issue.